# How I can create my own glyphicon in twitter bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I loved to use twitter bootstrap 3 ...I'm doing a project that need my own icon..current glyphicon was awesome..sometimes I need to use my own...

Let say I want to call my own glyphicon as below:

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-myown"></span>`